# Is it possible to redefine the base object valueOf to return an inner prop's value?

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects

**Question:**

*Is it possible to redefine the base object valueOf to return a inner prop?*

```
let obj = {
  x: 1,
  y: 2
}

obj     // 2 <- the value of obj.y
obj.x   // 1
obj.y   // 2
```

Comment: How do you get `2` from just `obj`?

Comment: @zer00ne because it returns the value of `obj.y`

Comment: no offence, but your question doesn't make sense for me . what kind of 'valueOf' are you looking for and for witch element ?

Comment: @MatthewHarwood only `obj.y` returns 2

Comment: What would be use case for this be if you could do it? Or what problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it's possible to define a `valueOf` method that returns a member, but you still need to call the method somehow - either implicitly in a conversion, or explicitly. `valueOf` doesn't magically make `obj` itself become a different thing.

```js
const obj = {
  x: 1,
  y: 2,
  valueOf() {
    return this.y;
  }
};

console.log(obj);
console.log(obj.x, obj.y)
console.log(obj.valueOf())
console.log(obj + 5)
console.log("y: " + obj)
```

Answer (score 1):

`valueOf`, `toString` and `toJSON` can be used to handle some (but not all) of the cases:

```js
var obj = { a: 1, 
            b: 2, 
            c: 3, 
            toJSON  : function() { return this.a }, 
            valueOf : function() { return this.b }, 
            toString: function() { return this.c } }

console.log( obj, +obj, `${obj}` )
```